# stackoverflow日本語版のGoogle検索の説明が分かりにくい

Tags: バグ, 完了

Google検索での日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの説明がCookieやプライバシーことのみ記載されており、どのようなサイトなのかの説明になっていないです。

すでに何のサイトか分かっている人はよいのですが、初めてこのサイトを見る人にはどのようなサイトか伝わりにくいです。

> このサイトを利用することによって、あなたはこのサイトのCookie Policy、Privacy Policy、およびTerms of Serviceを読んで理解し、同意したものとみなします。 質問 · タグ · ユーザー · バッジ · 質問する ...

[image: 日本語版の説明]

ちなみに英語版だとサイトの内容についての説明になっているようです。
[image: 英語版の検索結果]

Comment: +1: 確かにこれは分かりにくいですね。こういう文にしてほしいという具体例はありますか？（あれば、Stack Exchange の社員さんが対応しやすそうです）

Comment: ```
スタックオーバーフローはプログラミングのQ&Aサイトです。わからないことを質問するとほかの人が回答して、解決できます。
```
などはどうでしょうか?
サイトのmeta tagには`熱狂的でプロフェッショナルなプログラマーのためのQ&A`となっていますが、`熱狂的でプロフェッショナル`はプログラミング学習を始めた方には敷居が高そうなイメージを与えるかと思います

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローのバナーで使用されている「`スタック・オーバーフローはプログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人のためのQ&Aサイトです。` 」などでも良いかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 4):

METAタグのdescriptionをGoogleのクローラがうまく拾っていないような気がします。

日本語版、英語版ともにdescriptionに概要が設定されており、英語版の方で表示されているのはこのテキストですが、KiYugadgeter さんが貼られた日本語での検索結果ではなぜか反映されていないようです。
(ちなみに私が検索してもKiYugadgeter さんと同じ表示結果になりませんでした)

なお、代わりに DuckDuckGo で検索した場合には以下の様な結果になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [Search Console ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)を読む限り、必ずしも `meta` 要素で記述した説明が検索結果のスニペットに使用される訳ではなく、 `meta` 要素どおりの内容を表示する方法も見当たりませんでした。

Answer (score 3):

今朝の時点で、Stack Overflow を Google で 検索すると次のように表示され、Cookie やプライバシーに関する記載はありません。ご投稿いただいた「Google検索で、初めてこのサイトを見る人にはどのようなサイトか伝わりにくい」という問題については解決されたようにみえます。よって、この投稿を一旦完了とさせていただきます。投稿くださってから時間が経過してしまい、申し訳ありませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> 熱狂的でプロのプログラマーのためのQ&A.

なお、現在の文言の言い回しを変更する必要がある場合は、おそれいりますが、どうぞ新しい投稿でご提案くださいませ ‍♀️。